# Facebook Insights for my website won't update?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-insights

I am the owner of http://porkystuff.com, and have recently added it to my Facebook Insights. I was really impressed at first, but now it won't update since three days ago. What's up with that? I tried removing the meta-tag about who's admin on my page, and adding it again - no luck. Anyone know what's up with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook insights sometimes lags behind updating. The stats for several of my pages and sites and all behind by 2-3 days. You will just have to wait until Facebook catches up with the processing of all the data.